# Monitoring Delayed Jobs on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Delayed Jobs on Heroku.  How would I (easily) monitor the results of this worker?  Should I simply activate a Mailer that sends me an email (might get burdensome as it runs each minute).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out my friend Eric's [Delayed::Job Admin](http://github.com/eac/delayed_job_admin). If you turn off deleting failed jobs, you can use this admin page to look at your failed jobs, examine what went wrong, as well as seeing pending jobs that haven't yet run.

Comment: Looks like that link is broken and should be updated to point here: 

http://github.com/eac/delayed_job_admin

Comment: Weird. The link is right, but the slashes are getting escaped. Stack Overflow markdown bug?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [delayed_job_web](https://github.com/ejschmitt/delayed_job_web). It is quite active as of 2014.